# Putting a Label and PickerView on the same line in a TableView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is in C# with Xamarin. I"m using the cross-platform UI code. Similar to just using the .XAML file but I'm doing it in code.

```
     var viewPickerAutoSaveTimer = new StackLayout();
        viewPickerAutoSaveTimer.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        viewPickerAutoSaveTimer.Padding = 13;


        Label labelAutoSaveTimer = new Label()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Text = "Auto Save Timer"
        };

        Picker pickerAutoSaveTimer = new Picker()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            SelectedIndex = 1,

            Items = { "1", "2", "3" }
        };



    viewPickerAutoSaveTimer.Children.Add(labelAutoSaveTimer);
    viewPickerAutoSaveTimer.Children.Add(pickerAutoSaveTimer);
```

Next I have the following code..

```
                new TableSection ("AUTO SAVE") {
                    new SwitchCell {
                        Text = "Enable Auto Save:"
                    },
                    new ViewCell
                    {
                      View = viewPickerAutoSaveTimer
                    }


                },
```

Here is a screenshot of the result -
[image]

The line next to Auto Save Timer should display the selected item on the picker... but it does not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object initialization order is incorrect, you need to assign the picker items **before** you can set the item that is selected from that items' collection:

```
    Picker pickerAutoSaveTimer = new Picker()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Items = { "1", "2", "3" },
        SelectedIndex = 1,
    };
```

Comment: Still no go. Even if I tap the picker view and make a choice it doesn't display the selected item either!

Comment: @DavidKachlon Then you are not giving it enough room to display the control's full height, comment out `viewPickerAutoSaveTimer.Padding = 13;` and give that are try (along with the correct initialization order)

Comment: given that you said there isn't enough room to display the controls full height, I made a change to the ViewCell (upped the Height) and now I have the display functioning in the way I want it to.  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidKachlon No problem